# Redirect to https not working (and https itself not working)

Tags: javascript, linux, ssl, nginx, openssl

My goals are to get https to work, and then get the http to https redirections, and the non-www to www redirections to work.

Nginx.conf looks like:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    include site.conf;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

site.conf looks like:

```
upstream site_local {
   server 127.0.0.1:9090 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com;
    return 301 https://www.site.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site.com;
    return 301 https://www.site.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.site.com;
    set $app_root /home/site/site-web-node/public;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/SSL.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/site.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://site_local;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }

    location ~ /(app|lang|js) {
        root $app_root;
    }
}
```

`service nginx reload` is successful, however the website's https isn't working, nor the redirects. http is working as before.

nginx -t returns successful.

Comment: "https isn't working..." - any error messages you get from the browser site would be helpful. Also,  you might find error messages in the server logs.

Comment: What shows `sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 443`?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error
Its show me like this when i run sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10031/nginx

Then i found it was the site available server config file was the problem. Its working now.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer to the question